# mount_afp - failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied

Tags: raspbian, mount, share

I am trying to mount a mac share on my Pi with `mount_afp`. When I try to add permissions when mounting:

```
sudo mount_afp -o user=pi,group=pi afp://username:password@192.168.1.7/myshare ./mydir
```

I get this error:

```
FUSE reported the following error:
fuse: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied
Unknown error 1, 13.
```

I have tried

```
sudo usermod -aG fuse pi
exec su -l $USER
```

and

```
gpasswd -a pi fuse
```

If I remove the `-o user=pi,group=pi`, it will mount but I need to access the directory as root, which I am trying to avoid. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.XX/Passport /home/pi/passport -o user=johndoe,nounix,sec=ntlmssp
```

This mounts a mac share called `Passport` on 162.168.1.XX to a directory on my pi `/home/pi/passport`

Comment: This is a different approach and not a solution to the actual issue of using mount_afp.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a sequence of commands that work.  1-4 can be thought of as "setup" commands and 5 can be repeated for the same volume. Recommend using "pi" as the username on the macOS (aka AFP) server to keep confusion down on file ownerships.

1. `sudo apt-get install afpfs-ng -y`
2. `sudo apt-get install fuse -y`
3. `sudo mkdir -p /Volumes/volName`
4. `sudo chown pi:pi /Volumes/volName`
5. `afp_client mount -u pi -p piPasswordOnMacServer macServerIPAddress:volName /Volumes/volName`

Then to unmount the volume you do a:
`sudo umount /Volumes/volName`

where:

- `volName` - is the name of the "share" or volume you want the pi to access on your AFP server
- `piPasswordOnMacServer` - the password setup for the "pi" user on the AFP / macOS server

Here is the same thing but getting more towards a script...  The installs in #1 & #2 need not be repeated. The single command line for #3 can be used repeatedly with a different `volName` in your macOS (AFP) server that you want to mount:

1. `sudo apt-get install afpfs-ng -y`
2. `sudo apt-get install fuse -y`
3. `sudo mkdir -p /Volumes/volName;sudo chown pi:pi /Volumes/volName;afp_client mount -u pi -p piPasswordOnMacServer macServerIPAddress:volName /Volumes/volName`

Moving more towards a shell script, change the `macServerIPAddress`, `volName` and `piPasswordOnMacServer` to variables and feed them in as parameters to your shell script.

**Very important**, do ***not*** `sudo` the `afp_client` command or you can only access what you mount as `root`, forcing you to `sudo su` to use the mounted volume which has a bunch of negative side effects for use on the RBPi

Last note: you can `cd /Volumes/` but you cannot then `cd /volName/` as it will say no such file or directory. You need to `cd /Volumes/volName/` for the illusion to work.